# With automapper is it possible to map child collections in a separate query

Tags: .net, automapper

I use automapper extensively for reducing the payload of Sql queries by using ProjectTo on my entities to return a Dto. When the Entity has a child collection, it too can be mapped to a child collection of Dto objects in the target Dto. Works fine.

However, doing so creates queries where every line in the parent is duplicated for each line in the child collection.This is a real issue when the parent has a large nvarchar field, and there are lots of elements in the child collection.

Is it possible to configure Automapper so that the query is done in two parts? E.g.

1. Query the base object and ProjectTo the Dto
2. Query the child collection and ProjectTo the target child Dto collection

or does such an operation have to be done manually?

Comment: How would you do it with LINQ, without AM?

Comment: You wouldn't. This is looking at whether you can to it as multiple operations. Being EF specific, the first query gets the main object as projected to the Dto. Then one or more maps are done for subsequent queries. I was thinking something along the lines of AfterMap, but that is not an option for ProjectTo

Comment: That's my point. You would do it in two queries. So you need two ProjectTo calls.

Comment: All I wondering is, is there a way to do this in a config - similar to aftermap, rather than explicitly building the model in, for example a service. Apologies for clarity.

Comment: There isn't. A `ProjectTo` call is a `Select` statement.